# Update in R and code doesn't work anymore

Tags: r, version, updates, new-operator

I just updated my R and RStudio from Verison 2.xx to the newest version 4.0.5.
Now my code doesn't work anymore. The simplest functions like count() give an error.

How can a return to the older version or make the code work on the new version?

Thank you!

Comment: What type of error do you have when using `count()` for example ?

Comment: Error in UseMethod("count") : 
  no applicable method for 'count' applied to an object of class "character"

This error never appeared in the version before

Comment: Your are trying to use `plyr::count` but you are actually using `dplyr::count`. Try with `plyr::count(...)`.

Comment: That worked - thanks! 
In the old version I just entered ```library(plyr)``` in the beginning and then it worked. Why doesn't it work in the new version? Do I need to enter ```plyr::...``` every time? And how do I know which package I need to use in the new version?

Comment: I don't think `plyr` is supported well anymore. Are you also using any tidyverse package like `dplyr`? If so, that will share the same functions and may take precedent based on the order library was called. I've had a similar problem. E.g. I was using `data.table` and `config` package at one point and they both had a function called `merge`. Try typing `count` in the console and see what it reads back under the `<environment: namespace: ??  >` part. If you can I'd recommend moving to `dplyr`

Comment: Thank you Jonny Phelps and Ronak Shah for your help!